# how to convert initialization code that requires an action to F#

Tags: f#

I have the following C# code:

```
var client = new RestClient(url);
client.ConfigureWebRequest((r) =>
{
    r.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
    r.KeepAlive = true;
});
```

in F#, after I initialize the rest client, how can I structure the ConfigureWebRequest call? I don't know the syntax to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
client.ConfigureWebRequest(fun r ->
  r.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue <- false
  r.KeepAlive <- true
)
```